# CartoDB map not viewable by anyone, despite being public

Tags: carto

I have a map created with CartoDB, but when I give the bit.ly link to others, or view it in incognito, I see the message:

"Looks like this map no longer exists or is set as private."

This is the link to the map: http://bit.ly/1OwBmCB

The visibility is set to public.

How can I make it so that others can see this map?

Comment: Hi, I tried to create a new map and my bit.ly link is working. The link from your profile site https://majelbstoat.cartodb.com/maps is also not working. You should ask the cartodb support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the name of your dataset? This problem might be caused by this bug:

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/6138

If the dataset (not the map!) is established as public and the name starts with an underscore it causes the error that you are describing.

To solve this you would need to change the dataset name. For example if the name of your dataset is "_dataset", change it into "dataset".

Comment: That was it, thanks! (the dataset was called _final). I imagine this is pretty common, as exports of a single Google Sheet as CSV imports as _sheetName.